# How to configure systemd-journald on NixOS?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald, nixos

What is the proper way to configure `systemd-journald` on NixOS?  There seems to be no relevant [configuration options](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-boot.systemd.services).  On Ubuntu, for example, I could edit `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.

Context: I have recently discovered that by default `systemd-journald` can [use gigabytes](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/19du4x) of disk space for its journal, unless limited by `SystemMaxUse` configuration option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` is produced by the NixOS systemd [module](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/209730208a2ec0e3158303271d058dc851f83b99/nixos/modules/system/boot/systemd.nix#L748).

There are configuration [options](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#journald) for journald, but not one specifically for `SystemMaxUse`. What you can do is use the `services.journald.extraConfig` option to append whatever else you need to `journald.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the option when there is no other extraConfig

```
services.journald.extraConfig = "SystemMaxUse=100M";
```